# what is the advance poll tpl file name and where should it locate at?

Tags: theming, polls

I need to theme the advance poll, but not sure what the tpl file name and where should it located...
I had tried poll-vote.tpl.php inside mytheme templates file
I had tried poll-vote.tpl.php inside adv poll modules templates file
I also had tried advpoll-vote.tpl.php
but not working
(or this only work for poll modules but not adv poll?)
Anyone Please help!